# If both {1,2} x Z+ and Z+ x {1,2} are well ordered in the dictionary, do they have the same order type?

Tags: order-theory

Here, Z+ denotes positive integers. They cannot have the same order type. let A be the cartesian product such that  A={1,2} x Z+. and let B be the cartesian product such that B=Z+ x {1,2}.

Then the set A has this kind of ordering:
(1,1),(1,2),...,(2,1),(2,2),...
where all the elements in the first coordinate are either 1 or 2 and the second coordinate contains

On the other hand, the set B has this type of ordering:
(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),...
where the first coordinate contains positive integers and the second coordinate contains either a 1 or a 2.

Now, there is no order-preserving bijection from A to B because if we define a map g: A->B,
and we let g(2,1)=**(a,b)** where **a** belongs to set of integers, and **b** belongs to the set {1,2}, then (2,1) contains infinitely many predecessors that no element in B contains. So there is no bijection between the two. Therefore, they do not have the same order type.
I am not sure if this is the right way to explain this. I know from my intuition they do not have the same order type. But why?

Comment: That’s right. I think adding extra notation with $g$ muddies things a little - the point is that every element of $B$ has finitely many predecessors, but that is not true in $A$ by considering $(2,1)$.

Comment: @TokenToucan I'd suggest making this an answer.

Comment: Thank you! I thought this would be a good answer

Comment: Specifically, $\langle 2,1\rangle$ has infinitely many predecessors in $\{1,2\}\times\Bbb Z^+$, but each $\langle n,i\rangle\in\Bbb Z^+\times\{1,2\}$ has $(2n-2)+(i-1)=2n+i-3$ predecessors.

Answer (score 3):

Your idea is right, only I think adding the extra notation with $g$ muddies things. The point is that on $A$, some elements (such as $(2,1)$) have infinitely many predecessors, whereas that is not true in $B$, where every element has finitely many predecessors.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense